# change style of pseudo class jquery

Tags: jquery, pseudo-class

I want to change the style of burger menu button. But a pseudo Element has no style attribut. Thats why i don´t know how i change the color of the elements.

Here my code

```js
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function() {
    $( "button.burger.burger1:after span" ).animate({backgroundColor: "rgba(255,55,255,1)"}, 300 );
  });
```

```css
button.burger {
  width: 60%;
  height: 4vh;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
 
}
button.burger:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button.burger.burger1:after, button.burger.burger1:before,
button.burger.burger1 span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  
  background: black;
}
button.burger.burger1:after, button.burger.burger1:before {
  content: "";
}
button.burger.burger1:after {
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, 0.2s all 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}
button.burger.burger1:before {
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, 0.2s all 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, 0.2s all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}
button.burger.burger1 span {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s, svisibility 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, svisibility 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div style="width:50px;">
  <button class="burger burger1">
    <span id="burgerRows"></span>
  </button>
</div>


<button id="but"></button>
```

Its possible to change the middle row of the burger because its the original span element. 
I searched for that but didnt find a solution. I hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can not select pseudo elements with JavaScript because they are not actually in the DOM.

Instead just create 3 div's for the burger, and toggle a class when it's selected or not. When that class is selected, the 2nd div will get different styling.

By toggling classes you can make use of CSS transitions instead of being dependent on jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="burger">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
.burger div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.burger.selected div:nth-of-type(2) {
   background: red;
}
```

And the JS:

```
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');

burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bd4gufoa/

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to change the style of a pseudo-element using javascript, using one of several work-arounds. Please read this excellent tutorial by Pankaj Parashar at http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/